# Code complete keyboard shortcut in NetBeans on MBP

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

Just got a MBP and I cannot figure out the shortcut for code completion. Its says <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> but what is the <kbd>^</kbd> character?

Answer (score 3):

That typically represents Ctrl. `^M` means Ctrl-M, etc.

Comment: It is indeed Ctrl in this case.

Answer (score 0):

^ is indeed the control key. But on your MBP as on mine, you can open the code completion window by pressing +\ (command+backslash).